# Async servlet , why do we need it

Tags: java, asynchronous, servlets

I'm using Spring-boot for MVC projects with embedded tomcat(8).

I know about the following problem: when request is come we give one thread from tomcat connection pool to proceed this request,and for example we call some blocking API so our thread will do nothing except waiting and then return response for client. Now we have `Callable and DifferedResult` classes which use thread from executorservice that we will provide as `Bean` (otherwise it create new thread for each request)

For example Tomcat's connection pool is 100 threads, and connection pool for async calls is also 100, when request is come it get thread from Tomcat, then tomcat will get request to one of the worker thread from executor service and will return to the pool of Tomcat threads. But i don't understand , why do we need another thread pool , why we can't just increase the number of Tomcat threads to get the same result as with using worker pool ?

Comment: tomcat's thread can accept new network connection and probably serve it before result from async pool returned

Comment: so why we just can't increase the number of tomcat threads instead of using async support?

Comment: We can and usually we do, separate pools are useful if you have different types of queries, so heavy ones are executed without waisting network’s one

Comment: Tomcat's thread keep network connection with client even though it wait for blocking call , and this is more resource intensive than release this thread and use one from pool of CPU where server is running. Is this main reason to use Async support?

Comment: No, waiting for blocking call does not use resources, nor keeping client’s one (you have to keep connection open in both cases)

Comment: Sorry i don't understand , "heavy ones are executed without waisting network’s one" why we can't just increase the tomcat's pool size , can you provide some example where using async support will be better than usual sync support? Thank in advance

Comment: Then I cannot help, reread all my comments above

Comment: One of the simple reasons is that Spring simply doesn't have access to the Tomcat thread pool. It belongs to the web container, not to the application running in the container.

Comment: I can increase embedded tomcat's pool size through app.prop it's not the point